# How to inspect the UI component of android application?

Tags: android, testing, ui-automation

**I want to automate android application , for that i want to find out UI components**

Comment: Not an appropriate question. Please mention where exactly you are having issues, after exploring and trying first hand.

Answer (score 0):

If by "automate android application", you are referring to UI Automator, then you can [use **`uiautomatorviewer`**](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#uia-viewer) to inspect the UI of an app for the purposes of creating your integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uiautomatorviewer (found in sdk_folder/tools) to inspect the screen.

If you want to do it in runtime, then UiAutomator doesn't help you. I'm not sure if [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html) does though. Nevertheless you can read it with [UiAutomation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html) (if you use UiAutomator v2.0 that is now based on instrumentation).